# Google Sheets If False then Concatenate

Tags: google-sheets, concatenation, google-sheets-formula

```
=IF((E3=0,F3=0)," ",(CONCATENATE(TEXT(E3,"hh:mm AM/PM"))&" - "&TEXT(F3,"hh:mm AM/PM")))
```

I am trying to work in `Google Sheets` to put `two durations of time together` as a string. If the duration of time is 0 (nothing but also known as "12:00:00AM) then I want it to turn " ". I keep getting an error.

**UPDATE:**

I have tried

```
 =IF(OR(E6="12:00:00AM",F6="12:00:00 AM")," ",(CONCATENATE(TEXT(E6,"hh:mm AM/PM"))&" - "&TEXT(F6,"hh:mm AM/PM")))
```

There is no more error. But it is still returning the concatenation when the duration is zero.

Comment: "Formula Parse Error"

Comment: For starters, looks like you're missing an `AND` before `(E3=0,F3=0)`. Then, I bet you can drop the `CONCATENATE` and just use `&`.

Comment: =IF(AND(E3="12:00:00AM",F3="12:00:00 AM")," ",((TEXT(E3,"hh:mm AM/PM"))&" - "&TEXT(F3,"hh:mm AM/PM"))) when I use this it still would return the 12:00:00 @BigBen Should I change the beginning of this?

Comment: Nevermind! Got it! Thanks! =IF(AND(E3=0,F3=0)," ",((TEXT(E3,"hh:mm AM/PM"))&" - "&TEXT(F3,"hh:mm AM/PM")))

Comment: @GracieSmith you can add an answer to your question if you like.

Answer (score 0):

=IF(AND(E3=0,F3=0)," ",((TEXT(E3,"hh:mm AM/PM"))&" - "&TEXT(F3,"hh:mm AM/PM")))

This ended up working for me!